# how to restart pm2 in github action?

Tags: linux, mono, devops, github-actions, pm2

I am working on the Next.js project with GitHub Repository, for automation purposes, I am creating GitHub action for deploy my project in server with pm2.

```
try 1) ( github action for ssh ) 
uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master for ssh and run separate command
```

```
Error 1) pm2: command not found error
```

---

```
try 2) i was create 1 script file have commadn of restart pm2 after ssh in server snd run script file in linux server.
```

```
Error 2) 

$ sh /var/www/frontend/runpm2.sh
err: /var/www/frontend/runpm2.sh: 2: pm2: not found 
err: /var/www/frontend/runpm2.sh: 3: pm2: not found 
err: /var/www/frontend/runpm2.sh: 4: pm2: not found 
err: /var/www/frontend/runpm2.sh: 5: pm2: not found
.
.
.
```

as final need from my side is i want to restart pm2 of my hosted project Linux server which way is batter after this all try ? please help me solve this situation